# How to make theme elements customizable in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In Wordpress there's a menu option called 'Appeareances'.
I want to add (e.g.) a submenu 'header' there and then be able to customize the header from within wordpress (administration page).

From what I understood I have to have a 'functions.php' file in my theme folder. In the 'functions.php' file I write something like this:

```
<?php add_submenu_page( $parent_slug, $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function); ?>
```

Of course with adapted arguments (which I'm not entirely sure what those should be since I feel quite lost in all this).

Comment: [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) is your best friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CODEX](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) is your best friend ..

And like the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page) say, if you want to add an entry to the `'Appearance'` menu , use

> For Appearance: add_submenu_page( 'themes.php', ... );

or adapted to your case :

```
add_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'Header', 'Header', 'edit_theme_options', 'customize_header','my_callback');
```

But ..:

```
Also see
> add_theme_page()
```

like so :

```
 add_theme_page( $page_title, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function );
```

Quoting from codex :

> Parameters
>
> $page_title
>       (string) (required) The text to be displayed in the title tags of the page when the menu is selected
>
> ```
>     Default: None
> ```
>
> $menu_title
>       (string) (required) The text to be used for the menu
>
> ```
>     Default: None
> ```
>
> $capability
>       (string) (required) The capability required for this menu to be displayed to the user.
>
> ```
>     Default: None
> ```
>
> $menu_slug
>       (string) (required) The slug name to refer to this menu by (should be unique for this menu).
>
> ```
>     Default: None
> ```
>
> $function
>       (callback) (optional) The function to be called to output the content for this page.

**TL;DR version**

All the above said in general for custom menu entries, but in the specific case of custom header, all you actually need to use is :

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-header' );
```

See details here : http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Headers